# How to receive following data structure in Firebase from website using JavaScript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I want to receive data from JavaScript file using PHP in Firebase in following structure.

[image: Correct Data structure in Firebase]

Not like this.

[image: Not like this]

Comment: not rly understandable asked like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From how I understood your question, I think you're looking to have your data to be added with an auto-generated Firebase id. So I think what you're looking for is the [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) method:

> Generates a new child location using a unique key and returns its `Reference`.
>
> This is the most common pattern for adding data to a collection of items.
>
> If you provide a value to `push()`, the value will be written to the generated location. If you don't pass a value, nothing will be written to the Database and the child will remain empty (but you can use the `Reference` elsewhere).
>
> The unique key generated by `push()` are ordered by the current time, so the resulting list of items will be chronologically sorted. The keys are also designed to be unguessable (they contain 72 random bits of entropy).

Also see [Firebase Database: Read and Write Data on the Web - Update specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).